# generic Caster for method reflection

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I have a Map of methods(getter methods) , I invoke them on some object , the getter method returns different types of data  i.e.  int string etc...
am trying to do something like

```
String col1= <method name>; //getId()
Class c = colGetterMap.get(col1).getReturnType();
(c) colGetterMap.get(col1).invoke(object);
```

but am getting

```
cannot find symbol Class c
```

Comment: Casting is a compile time concept, not a run time concept.

Comment: it's not in run time ... it's the Netbeans warning thing...

Comment: Yes it fails at compile time specifically because what you are attempting to do makes no sense at run time.

Comment: Yes I know and the question is how to achieve this casting... :)

Comment: You cannot achieve that. What is it you want to do with the result of `invoke(..)`?

Comment: am calling different methods those are (Getter methods like getId() , getName() etc...) so each of those return different type of data , Integers , Strings etc... so I want to cast the type to the method being called.

Comment: Cast it and do what with the casted result?

Comment: will it's pretty complicated... because am gonna use it in a sql statement in a WHERE clause... so don't go too far ... just worry about the casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do casting, you put class name in brackets, ie `String string = (String) obj`

in your case, you are trying cast to instance. `c` is just instance of class `Class<?>`,
 so to do this properly, invoke cast method on your class instance `c.cast(colGetterMap.get(col1).invoke(object))` now it should work

Comment: hmm am getting this error now
"Cannot cast java.lang.Long to long" how can I fix it ?